# Makefile.am: How to link a dynamic library only if the library exists/is installed on the system

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, gnu, configure, automake

I have a dynamic library /usr/lib64/liba-3.2.so.1. And, I am trying to change Makefile.am so that myprog_LDADD can link against this library if the file exists. Is there any way to do it?

I tried this:

```
if [ -f /usr/lib64/liba-3.2.so.1 ]; then myprog_LDADD += /usr/lib64/liba-3.2.so.1 ; fi;
```

But this is not working. Any suggestions on how to make Makefile.am link against a library if the library exists? Thanks!

Comment: And what if the system *doesn't* have that library available?  How will the symbols be resolved that otherwise would be resolved against the library?

Comment: It's unclear to me what exactly you're after, since what you've described doesn't make sense by itself.  But here are some suggested search terms: automake conditional.

Answer (score 0):

the usual way would of course be to use your `configure(.ac)` (`autotools`) to check for the existance of a library and then use the the result to tell your `Makefile(.am)` to link against the library.

Snippet from `configure.ac`:

```
AC_CHECK_LIB([a-3.2], [a_fun], [A_LIBS="-la-3.2"])
AC_SUBST([A_LIBS])
```

and the corresponding snippet from `Makefile.am`:

```
myprog_LDADD += @A_LIBS@
```

Note that this will look for `liba-3.2.so` in all the (default) search paths of the linker, and without the `.1` suffix, but I think this is the correct behavior anyhow (and you explicit linking against `/usr/lib64/liba-3.2.so.1` is bound to fail in multiple scenarios starting with non-64bit platforms, so I'd consider this over-adaption)